# A simple differential equation system by Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, dsolve

I'm trying to solve the below simple differential equation with Sympy

```
import sympy as sp
x, y = sp.symbols('x, y', cls= sp.Function)
t = sp.symbols('t')
m = 5
a = -9.8
eq1, eq2 = sp.Eq(y(t).diff(t,2),m*a), sp.Eq(x(t).diff(t,2),0)
sp.dsolve((eq1,eq2))
```

But I get an error saying 
*local variable 'gsol1' referenced before assignment*. What would be the problem?

Comment: This is a bug: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19238

Comment: @OscarBenjamin thanks for your comment. So I have to wait for the next release.

Comment: If you don't want to wait, you can use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`. I believe it will do the same thing. I can also provide an example of how to use it in the solutions if you want.

Comment: @gnahum thanks for your attention. In fact, I would like to implement in analytically for educational purpose.